# Set variable position for geom_segment based on the input data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add a vertical line to my plot that serves as reference line for the performance of the benchmark method. However, I cannot figure out how I can define the `y`-value based on my data.

Here is a completely reproducible example with the desired plot:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(16)
tibble("X"=rep(c("Reference.A", "1.A", "2.A", "Reference.B", "1.B", "2.B"),3), 
       "Decision"=c(rep("Type 1",6),rep("Type 2",6),rep("Type 3",6)), 
       "Outcome"=c(rnorm(n=6,mean=50,sd=5),rnorm(n=6,mean=30,sd=5),rnorm(n=6,mean=20,sd=5))) %>%
  ggplot(., aes(X, Outcome, color=Decision, shape=Decision, size=2)) + geom_point(stroke=2, alpha = 0.8) + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("Reference.A", "1.A", "2.A", "Reference.B", "1.B", "2.B")) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 1, y = 52.4, xend = 3, yend = 52.4), color="black", linetype="dashed", size=1) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = 4, y = 42.8, xend = 6, yend = 42.8), color="black", linetype="dashed", size=1)
```

[image]

The `Outcome` of decision `Type 1` of `Reference.A` should be compared to the methods `1.A` and `2.A`, and correspondingly for the `B`-Methods. `Type 2` and `Type 3` should not be indicated by such a benchmark line.

In the example, I've set the values for `y` manually, but my data changes often, so it would be perfect to have a flexible solution. Does somebody know a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filter` the data for your `geom_segment` layer (you only need one):

```
tibble("X"=rep(c("Reference.A", "1.A", "2.A", "Reference.B", "1.B", "2.B"),3), 
       "Decision"=c(rep("Type 1",6),rep("Type 2",6),rep("Type 3",6)), 
       "Outcome"=c(rnorm(n=6,mean=50,sd=5),rnorm(n=6,mean=30,sd=5),rnorm(n=6,mean=20,sd=5))) %>% 
  ggplot(. , aes(X, Outcome, color=Decision, shape=Decision, size=2)) + 
  geom_point(stroke=2, alpha = 0.8) + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("Reference.A", "1.A", "2.A", "Reference.B", "1.B", "2.B")) +
  geom_segment(
    aes(x = c(1, 4), y = Outcome, xend = c(3, 6), yend = Outcome), 
    data = . %>% filter(Decision == 'Type 1', X %in% c('Reference.A', 'Reference.B')),
    color="black", linetype="dashed", size=1
  )
```

This uses the `. %>%` trick to define a functional sequence, since you need to pass a function as the data argument because you pipe in your data.

Alternatively:

```
d <- tibble("X"=rep(c("Reference.A", "1.A", "2.A", "Reference.B", "1.B", "2.B"),3), 
       "Decision"=c(rep("Type 1",6),rep("Type 2",6),rep("Type 3",6)), 
       "Outcome"=c(rnorm(n=6,mean=50,sd=5),rnorm(n=6,mean=30,sd=5),rnorm(n=6,mean=20,sd=5)))

ggplot(d , aes(X, Outcome, color=Decision, shape=Decision, size=2)) + 
  geom_point(stroke=2, alpha = 0.8) + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("Reference.A", "1.A", "2.A", "Reference.B", "1.B", "2.B")) +
  geom_segment(
    aes(x = c(1, 4), y = Outcome, xend = c(3, 6), yend = Outcome), 
    data = filter(d, Decision == 'Type 1', X %in% c('Reference.A', 'Reference.B')),
    color="black", linetype="dashed", size=1
  )
```